# How to use javascript to loop through key , values and add up one key's value when the other's match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dataset of records that look like this :

```
[{
 "d1d":"2015-05-28T00:00:00.000Z",
 "d1h":0,
 "d15m":0,
 "ct":3
},
{
 "d1d":"2015-05-28T00:00:00.000Z",
 "d1h":0,
 "d15m":0,
 "ct":1
}
]
```

The ct value changes in every record.  If d1d, d1h, and d15m are the same in one or more records, I need to combine those records into one with the sum of all the ct values.

I do have jquery, can I use grep for this?

I realize the server side could do a better job of getting me this data , but I have zero control over that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use jQuery for this, vanilla JavaScript will do.
I'll show you two solutions to your problem;

## Example 1: Abusing [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as an iterator

```
var intermediaryArray = [];
dataset.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  if(prev.d1d === curr.d1d && prev.d1h === curr.d1h && prev.d15m === curr.d15m) {
    intermediaryArray.push({
      d1d: prev.d1d,
      d1h: prev.d1h,
      d15m: prev.d15m,
      ct: prev.ct + curr.ct
    });
  } else {
    // push the one that wasn't the same
    intermediaryArray.push(curr);
  }
  // return current element so reduce has something to work on
  // for the next iteration.
  return curr;
});
```

## Example 2: Using [Array#Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and Array#Reduce in conjunction

This example utilises [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) to demonstrate the logic behind what you want to do.

`.map()` produces the new array of grouped objects.
`.groupBy()` produces an array of subarrays containing the objects that pass the predicate that all objects must share the same `d1d` or grouping function.
`.reduce()` boils all subarrays down to one value, your object with both `ct`s added to each other.

```
var merged = _.map(_.groupBy(a, 'd1d'), function(subGroup) {
  return subGroup.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return {
      d1d: prev.d1d,
      d1h: prev.d1h,
      d15m: prev.d15m,
      ct: prev.ct + curr.ct
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you possibly do a fiddle or your choice of js online editor for this one? Running this as is only eliminates one record from the array when i have 100 or so, and many of them match.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution:

```
var dataset = [{
 "d1d":"2015-05-28T00:00:00.000Z",
 "d1h":0,
 "d15m":0,
 "ct":3
},
{
 "d1d":"2015-05-28T00:00:00.000Z",
 "d1h":0,
 "d15m":0,
 "ct":1
}
]

function addCt(dataset) {
  var ctMap = {}
  var d1d, d1h, d15m, ct, key, value
  for (var ii=0, record; record=dataset[ii]; ii++) {
    key = record.d1d+"|"+record.d1h+"|"+record.d15m
    value = ctMap[key]
    if (!value) {
      value = 0
    }
    value += record.ct
    ctMap[key] = value
  }

  return ctMap
}

ctMap = addCt(dataset)
console.log(ctMap)
// { "2015-05-28T00:00:00.000Z|0|0": 4 }
```

You may want to construct the key in a different way. You may want set the value to an object containing the d1d, d1h, d15m and cumulated ct values, with a single object for all matching d1d, d1h and d15m values.